# disable and or enable button when checkbox checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to disable or enable button when checkbox checked. this checkbox is in the loop of data
so thereis many checkox , i get the checkbox using className

```
<input type="checkbox"  name='checked[]' class='check' onclick="aktifkan()"  id='checked'  value="<?= $data['gedung'];  ?>"> <!-- [] di pilih[] untuk menampung multiple checkbox -->
```

button will enable if checkbox if checked and will disable when checkbox uncheck

```
<button class="btn btn-succes btn-sm pull-right mb-2" disabled id="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right mb-2" disabled id="hapus" onclick='hapus()'>delet</button>         

const cekbox     = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
const editt      = document.getElementById('edit');
const hapuss     = document.getElementById('hapus');
function aktifkan (){
    var i ;
    var j = cekbox.length;
    for( i = 0 ; i<= j ; i++){
        // if checkbox.checked = true; theb button.disabled = false
        if (cekbox[i].checked == true){
            editt.disabled = false;
            hapuss.disabled = false ;
        }
        // if checkbox.checke = false; then button.disabled = true
        else{
            editt.disabled = true;
            hapuss.disabled = true;
        }

    }            

}
```

Comment: Whats your expected output ? Your code looks fine and is working as per the title of this question.

Comment: mozila firefox   Uncaught TypeError: cekbox[i] is undefined
    aktifkan http://localhost:81/mitra_medika/poliklinik/data.php?hal=1:272
    onclick http://localhost:81/mitra_medika/poliklinik/data.php?hal=1:1

Comment: Your code works in general, just use `for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {` instead of `for( i = 0 ; i<= j ; i++){`. Have a look https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/5L2xnpsq/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the important information about the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing you want :

```js
const cekbox = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
const editt = document.getElementById('edit');
const hapuss = document.getElementById('hapus');

function aktifkan() {
  let j = cekbox.length;
  let found = false;
  for (let i = 0; (i < j) && !(found); i++) {
    // if checkbox.checked = true;
    if (cekbox.item(i).checked == true) {
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    // checkbox is checked
    editt.disabled = false;
    hapuss.disabled = false;
  } else {
    // checkbox is not checked.
    editt.disabled = true;
    hapuss.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: so aktifkan() just work for last checkbox . i want when any checkbox checked the button will enable and if no one checkbox checked the button will disabled. here is the erro in mozila fire fox -  mozila firefox Uncaught TypeError: cekbox[i] is undefined aktifkan localhost:81/mitra_medika/poliklinik/data.php?hal=1:272 onclick localhost:81/mitra_medika/poliklinik/data.php?hal=1:1